# Android console error - The specified activity does not exist! Getting the launcher activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

i recently changed the app i'm developing around a bit so that i now have a splash screen activity that performs some data management, this activity is simply splash_screen_activity which when done launches the orginal main_activity and finishes itself.

ever since i have made this change i'm getting an "error" (red text) in the console of eclipse stating: The specified activity does not exist! Getting the launcher activity.

however this doesn't appear to effect the app at all, it still starts up fine and closes fine after use etc, it does however pull focus to the console which is annoying for debugging.

does anyone have any clue as to why this "error" is occurring?, if it has an underling issues that will jump out one day? and how to stop it?

heres the relevant part of my manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Splash_Screen_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Main_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name>
    </activity>
```

error log of event.

```
[2013-08-06 14:58:34 - InFish] Android Launch!
[2013-08-06 14:58:34 - InFish] adb is running normally.
[2013-08-06 14:58:34 - InFish] The specified activity does not exist! Getting the launcher activity.
[2013-08-06 14:58:34 - InFish] Performing com.example.Splash_Screen_Activity activity launch
```

Comment: can you share your error logs as well?

Comment: error log added, it doesnt seem very helpful though haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the way you launch you app. If you use shortcut or other launch configs using adb modify those to start the splash screen instead

Comment: ahhh i knew it was going to be something unrelated to the app, the run configuration was indeed set to launch using main explicitly which is no longer the launch activity causing this "error" to show, thankyou sir