# Android console error show No activity specified! Getting the launcher activity

Tags: android

I  recently have  changed my app little bit. And it now generate these in console

```
[2013-12-05 14:37:28 - Citytouch] Android Launch!
[2013-12-05 14:37:28 - Citytouch] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-05 14:37:28 - Citytouch] No activity specified! Getting the launcher activity.
```

But this error does not effect my app,it works fine.I am concerned about this error if it causes any further severe error in future.I search this 
   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071358/android-console-error-the-specified-activity-does-not-exist-getting-the-launc) But it does not help me.
My manifest file is....

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity

        android:name="com.thecitybank.citytouch.SplashActivity"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <activity
        android:name="com.thecitybank.citytouch.Tabactivty"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity

        android:name="com.thecitybank.citytouch.ParticularMapactivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thecitybank.citytouch.NotificationActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.thecitybank.citytouch" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.thecitybank.citytouch.GCMIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.thecitybank.citytouch.GpsTracker" >
    </service>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDrnKNJF3nWMs-MDseo5LE34UhMg195weo" />
    <!-- relese: android:value="AIzaSyDLmr8GZu9LP1l5fTEze1meET5d1h5kKlQ" -->
    <!-- android:value="AIzaSyCea8B9EuvTj1k9KBkbukyHgstRzbBz9vI" -->

</application>
```

Comment: Have you recently changed the name of the activity that has ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER? Do you have a shortcut button for your app on the HOME screen? If so, you might want to remove the shortcut button and recreate it.

Comment: Still show this error.